# Having a rigidBody to follow (match) the position of a gameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to use `addForceAtPosition` to make a `rigidBody` (the clone) to follow a `gameObject` (the target), more precisely to go the the same position and rotation.
This is my code:

```
        for(var points=0;points<3;points++)
        {
            Vector3 pr=Vector3.zero;
            switch(points)    //get some test points used as anchors
            {
                case 0: pr= new Vector3(0, 0, 0); break;
                case 1: pr = new Vector3(0, 0.05f, 0); break;
                case 2: pr = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.05f); break;
            }
            p = clone.transform.TransformPoint(pr);    //get the clone test point world position
            v = clone.GetPointVelocity(p);             //and its velocity
            pc = target.transform.TransformPoint(pr);    //get the target body test point world position

            Vector3 dist= (pc - (p + v * kv));    //add a part of the velocity to the position to reduce "elastic effect" (that part works)
            Vector3 force = dist * k;
            clone.AddForceAtPosition(force, p, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
```

The clone move to a position around the target but at a given distance and if tha target rotate, the clone move around it keeping a relative position to it.
It's seems to be a relative/absolute position problem but I don't see where I made a mistake.

Comment: Please attach an image of the hierarchy, to know if the clones are childs of the following object, or not

Comment: Just a note, it's hard to follow your code because of your use of abbreviations. Better write out variable names more fully for clarity. For instance, it's unclear what `kv` or `k` are (and variables like `pc`, while defined, also don't look intuitive). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you say set  a Rigidbody to `the same position and rotation.` as another object rather use [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) and [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)

```c#
private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    clone.MovePosition(targetTransform.position);
    clone.MoveRotation(targetTransform.rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The target parent have a scaling of 100 then the `target.transform.TransformPoint(pr)` returns a point far from the object.

`target.transform.TransformPoint(pr*0.01)` solved my issue.